# how to add image to SP 2010 WebPart

Tags: web-part

**UPDATE**: i want to do that in all in code-behind and i know you can do that in feature.xml but i am not sure how exactly.

I am creating a custom web part and i am looking for a way to have my logo (image) when the user add the web part as show in the image.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display an icon next to the web part title as per your first screenshot by setting the "Title Icon Image URL" property under Advanced in the Web Part Toolpane.

Comment: i updated my question....

Comment: In that case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.titleiconimageurl.aspx

Comment: will that work for the second screen shot?

Comment: Probably not. I had a quick look myself to see how you set that image. I'm not too sure myself as I can't see where it's set. Hopefully someone else will know...

Comment: I think the only way to customize the second url is by using `WebPartGalleryItemBase.IconUrl` when adding a `<WebPartAdderExtension>`. Read more about those on my blog here  http://sites.wizdim.com/andersrask/sharepoint-2010/creating-a-web-part-hub-in-sharepoint-2010/ or @Wictor 's blog [here](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Dynamically-populate-the-Web-Part-Gallery-using-the-WebPartAdder-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

just you know guys for the second screen shot you can have the imageurl icon through
`WebPart.CatalogIconImageUrl Property`

below are the two links that helps me.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.catalogiconimageurl.aspx

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Web-Part-Properties-part-3-the-webpart-file.aspx